# Algorithm or GDAL module to calculate LOS

Tags: gdal, analysis

I'm involved in a project using GDAL via python.

We need to be able to calculate if, standing at point A it is possible to see point B, given a DEM. To clarify we do *not* need a viewshed algoritm, we would only like to know if there is a straight unbroken line from A to B.

- Are there any well known algorithms for line-of-sight calculations?
- Is there a GDAL module or python script (using GDAL) that can do LOS calculation?

Comment: GRASS has modules to calculate view-shed and LOS. See r.viewshed and r.los. In GRASS 7.x you can call them from a python script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mention that you don't want a full viewshed (i.e. a raster output), which suggests that a simple point-to-point intervisibility is more what you're after.

There is a QGIS plugin called **Viewshed analysis**. As well as the usual raster options, this also has an intervisibility vector option.

If you have a layer with a number of  points, scattered over the DEM, you can get it to draw lines between any pairs of points which are mutually intervisible, like so:-

[image]

(in this case I added 200 points at random on a DEM, and chose to show only pairs which are mutually visible)

The options look like this. Make sure to choose a radius in Map Units, and make sure to complete both layer names - if you don't, you'll end up with one raster per point :-)

[image]

As it's a plugin, rather than a processing algorithm, it's not amenable to scripting unfortunately.. but it's open source, so you might be able to [look at the source](https://github.com/zoran-cuckovic/QGIS-visibility-analysis) to see how this is implemented.

The code repo also has a .bib file with links to papers which might be of interest

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. We managed to write our own python module for extracting a "straight" line in a raster between two points. In the end it was quite similar to a method in the `doViewshed.py` file from the source-code you suggested. We could then use the histogram we get to calculate inter-visibility between the points.

Comment: @GabrielTigerström Have you by any chance uploaded this code to Github? I'm looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented line of sight directly into GDAL. Here is the issue and pull request. It will be part of 3.9.

- https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/9050
- https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/9506

Review the tests in the PR for how to use it. The API is not yet stable, but I can update the answer once it's released with example code.